# Convert letter from textBox to an integer

Tags: c#, string, int

How do I convert alphabet letter from `textBox` to an integer?

For example, if the user inputs `"B"` in the `textBox`, I am trying to convert `B` to the number `1`

```
string a = textBox1.Text
int number = 1;

number = int.Parsed (a);

messageBox.Show(number.ToString());
```

Comment: how does b correlate to 1? is the text always 1 letter? if it is you could do `text.ToUpper()[0] - 65`

Answer (score 2):

Your first task is to capture only the first character from the input:

```
string str = textBox1.Text;
char chr = str[0]; // get first character
```

Now the character can be directly converted to an integer, for example:

```
int number = (int)chr;
```

However, the character `'A'` is actually represented by the number 65, `'B'` 66, and so on (see [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)), so you'll have to subtract that from your input to get the intended value:

```
int value = number - 65;
```

Or if you prefer:

```
int value = number - (int)'A';
```

Now you might want to normalize input so a character `'a'` will be treated as `'A'`, so in the end it would look a bit like this:

```
string str = textBox1.Text.ToUpperCase();
char chr = str[0];
int number = (int)chr;
int value = number - 65;
MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
```

Comment: While I agree with your approach i think `a` as a variable may seem confusing when you mention `A`, I would add an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) also